# Iterate over a categorical and a numerical data frames and ploting a bar chart in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a numeric data frame call `A` and a categoriacal one call `B`
For every two variables (one from `B` and one from `A`) I want to plot a bar chart.

My try:

```
y <- unlist(lapply(D, Negate(is.numeric)))
x <- unlist(lapply(D, is.numeric))    
A <- D[,x]
B <- D[,y]
A <- as.data.frame(A)
B <- as.data.frame(B)

for(i in (1:ncol(A)))
{
  for(j in (1:ncol(B)))
  {
    ggplot(D, aes(x = A[,i], y = B[,j])) +
    geom_bar(fill='red') 
  }
}
```

But is not plotting anything. I'm not sure if it's necessary to save each plot in a vector and then plot them with another for. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to wrap the ggplot statement inside the `print()` function to generate output while inside a loop:

```
for(i in (1:ncol(A)))
{
  for(j in (1:ncol(B)))
  {
    g<- ggplot(D, aes(x = A[,i], y = B[,j])) +
             geom_bar(fill='red') 
    print(g)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace `geom_bar()` with `geom_col()` or to add `stat = identity` inside `geom_bar()`.

You can also avoid using the `for` loop by using `pmap` from package `purrr`:

```
 df <- expand.grid(
    i = 1:ncol(A),
    j = 1:ncol(B)
)

purrr::pmap(
    list(df$i, df$j),
    function(.i, .j){
        tmp <- ggplot(D, aes(x = A[,.i], y = B[,.j])) +
            geom_col(fill='red')
        print(tmp)
    }
)
```

I should also add that you can assign the result of `pmap` to an object (e.g. `p`) and then call each charts using `p[[k]]`.